# DENSE_RANK() with two order by columns with the same value

Tags: sql, ssms, dense-rank

I'm trying to rank a list of payments using `DENSE_RANK()` function and ordering the results by two data points `[PAYROLL DATE]` and `[PROCESS DATE]`. However, when the two columns in the `ORDER BY` are the same, the `DENSE_RANK()` is treating them as the same rank.

Here is a snippet of what my query says.

```
DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY [Plan ID], [EE ID], [Loan Number] 
                   ORDER BY ISNULL([PAYROLL DATE], [PROCESS DATE]) ASC)
```

| [Plan ID] | [EE ID] | [Loan Num] | [PAYROLL DATE] | [PROCESS DATE] | (Desired) RANK | (Actual) RANK |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC123 | 1234 | 1 | 11/26/2021 | NULL | 1 | 1 |
| ABC123 | 1234 | 1 | 12/23/2021 | NULL | 2 | 2 |
| ABC123 | 1234 | 1 | 02/18/2022 | NULL | 3 | 3 |
| ABC123 | 1234 | 1 | 02/18/2022 | NULL | 3 | 3 |
| ABC123 | 1234 | 1 | NULL | 02/18/2022 | 4 | 3 |

In the above example, I want the ranking to go from 1 to 4. What I am seeing is that all three records with dates of 2/18 are being lump together (all ranked as 3). Is there another function I should use to get the results I want?

Thank you in advance!

I've tried different variations of `DENSE_RANK()` to no avail. I've also tried `RANK()` and `ROW_NUMBER()` and nothing is truly giving me what I'm looking for in the results.

Comment: And why isn't `row_number` giving you the desired results? If you replace dense_rank with row_number, it should give you 1 thru 4.

Comment: ROW_NUMBER does number them 1-4, but I have rows where Payroll Date is the same and I want those to be ranked together. I'm going to see if I can edit my question to make this clearer.

Comment: Yes, please edit your question, to include the desired results, too.

Comment: Done. I hope my edits make it clearer! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to using a `case expression` in your order by clause to manage those null values.

```
create table table1 (
  plan_id varchar(10), 
  ee_id integer, 
  loan_number integer, 
  payroll_date date, 
  process_date date);
```

```
insert into table1 values 
('aaa', 1234, 1, '2021-11-26', null), 
('aaa', 1234, 1, '2021-12-23', null), 
('aaa', 1234, 1, '2022-02-18', null), 
('aaa', 1234, 1, '2022-02-18', null), 
('aaa', 1234, 1, null, '2022-02-18');
```

```
select plan_id, ee_id, loan_number, payroll_date, process_date, 
 DENSE_RANK() OVER 
  (PARTITION BY plan_id,ee_id,loan_number ORDER BY case when payroll_date is null then 1 else 0 end, payroll_date,process_date asc) as r  
from table1
```

| plan_id | ee_id | loan_number | payroll_date | process_date | r |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| aaa | 1234 | 1 | 2021-11-26 | *null* | 1 |
| aaa | 1234 | 1 | 2021-12-23 | *null* | 2 |
| aaa | 1234 | 1 | 2022-02-18 | *null* | 3 |
| aaa | 1234 | 1 | 2022-02-18 | *null* | 3 |
| aaa | 1234 | 1 | *null* | 2022-02-18 | 4 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/JuA6Rb-L)

**EDIT**

Or, continue using your ISNULL expression but use a far-fetched future date instead of the process_date. HOWEVER, this alternate answer may not provide desired results if you have more than one null payroll_date row with the same partitioned_by columns, but different process_dates. This works fine if null appears just once. Therefore, I would probably stick with the case expression answer.

```
select plan_id, ee_id, loan_number, payroll_date, process_date, 
 dense_RANK() OVER 
  (PARTITION BY plan_id,ee_id,loan_number ORDER BY isnull(payroll_date,'9999-12-31') asc) as r  
from table1
```

Comment: Yes!!! That works exactly how I wanted it to work!! Thank you so much! Can I ask a follow up question? Why does it work? What does the CASE statement do when added to an ORDER BY in this way? I've not used a CASE statement in this way, so I want to know more so I may apply this logic in the future. Thank you so much!

Comment: The `isnull()` function you were using is replacing the null payroll date with the process date. And in that example, they are the same; therefore, were getting the same dense_rank. You could still use the isnull function with an extreme future date instead of the case expression. I will update my answer in a minute with that alternate option.

Comment: If you find this answer acceptable, then please consider marking the accept flag to let others know it's been resolved.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation, it makes a lot more sense now why it works the way it does. Thank you so much for your patience with my question and not making me feel dumb. :-) I've marked your answer as the solution.